# Facebook authentication query string missing

Tags: facebook

I created a Facebook canvas app. 
I tried using the app as a user. After clicking 'Allow' button in permission dialog, facebook showing my application but I am not getting the authentication query string "code".

I have selected authentication option as query string (code=...)

Any tips to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Enhanced Auth Dialog, Facebook stopped supporting query string authentication. signed_request is posted as request body.